How can I improve performance of a joined PostgreSQL query that orders by columns from different tables?
My query looks like this
select "vehicles".* from "vehicles"
left join "users" on "vehicles"."user_id" = "users"."id" 
where "vehicles"."status" not in ('draft', 'deactivated') and "vehicles"."auction_id" = 292 
order by users.dealership_name ASC, vehicles.year ASC, vehicles.make ASC, vehicles.model ASC, vehicles.vin ASC;

Is there anything I can do to speed up this query?
Besides indexes for where and join conditions, I have separate index for users.dealership_name ASC and vehicles.year ASC, vehicles.make ASC, vehicles.model ASC, vehicles.vin ASC, but it seems like they are not applied to the query.
I know that denormalization would solve this problem, but I would rather find some simpler option, as refactoring can be rough. If that helps, this is how my explain analyze query looks like


The query completes in three milliseconds. Is that not fast enough?

The sort takes 0.1 millisecond. How fast should it be?

This is a great example of the ability to measure very short times intervals but ignoring any meaning. This query runs literally in the blink of an eye (actually much faster as the blink of an eye averages 100ms). If you reduce the total time by an order of magnitude - no one will ever notice. Leave it (inho) and move on to something that requires your attention.

Ideally you have an index that finds the vehicles quickly and gets you right to the users.
create index idx1 on vehicles (auction_id, status) include (user_id);

If it is typical for your queries to be interested only in status not in ('draft', 'deactivated') or if you consider this query worthwile to get a very special index, then you can even make an index especially for these queries resp. this one query:
create index idx1 on vehicles (auction_id) include (user_id)
  where status not in ('draft', 'deactivated');

Then have an index to get the users quickly:
create index idx2 on users (id);

You can enhance this index a bit by changing it into a covering index containing all columns you need from the users table:
create index idx2 on users (id) include (dealership_name);

Thus the users table itself doesn't have to be read.
(It is a bit strange by the way that you order your results by a column you don't show. Thus the results will seam somewhat unordered to the viewer.)

thank you, did not know about the include on index, will read more about it

The CREATE INDEX ... WHERE is even more powerful, because it creates an index on only the rows you are generally interested in. The documentation of CREATE INDEX is here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html

It looks like include is not available for me because the project runs on 9.6 version of postgres, updating the question

Then add the column at the end of the index instead, e.g. create index idx2 on users (id, dealership_name);.

You shouldn't work with such an old version, anyway. 9.6 has long run out of support.
